# Recompile PHP with ZTS enabled on MAC OS X

Tags: php, pthreads, homebrew, macos-catalina, zts

Homebrew PHP does not support a thread-safe php binary. Is there any way to enable ZTS in brew version.

I tried phpbrew as well but, I am getting an error "Command too long". Could you please suggest me the best way to enable ZTS in MACOS Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

Which command is used? Complete your question by providing the entire error and return of the console.

You will need to recompile PHP with the parameters: `--enable-maintainer-zts or --enable-zts on Windows`

[See more on PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.requirements.php)